# Can't start some apps, problem might have to do with ttf fonts

Tags: unity, 14.04, fonts

I'm on a fresh install of x86 14.04, having trouble starting some applications, and the problem apparently has something to do with ttf fonts.

When I start a few apps, for example roguelike game dungeon crawl stone soup, installed from the software center, I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find font '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

I tried a few other apps, what happens is they just show a black screen for a second and then I go back to desktop, and the error reporter starts.

If I start them from the terminal, I can see what the error is, it's not identical for every app, but mostly it shows `"could not find a .ttf"` or, `"a .ttf does not exist"`.

I checked, I have restricted extras and the actual fonts installed.
Tried changing the permissions on the actual files and folders themselves,
even changed the ownership of usr to myself, but the error persists.

I can't check whether or not the live system has the problem on this machine right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are certain the files are there, in the place the app expects them, you should report this as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-dejavu and fonts-dejavu-core
```

After that:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

It might be necessary to repeat the copy process for all the fonts in the family:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
```

Comment: And this fixed it, the apps that had problems all start up correctly now. Thank you very much for the quick and helpful answer.

Comment: @Cornelius instead of the copy, you can `cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/` and then `ln -s dejavu ttf-dejavu`. Although this is probably a bug in that applications, you are not supposed to rely on the exact position of the font files...

Comment: Thanks! This got foobillardplus working for me. It was crashing with the cryptic message, "Another error code means that the font file could not e opened or read, or simply that it is broken." See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239485

Answer (score -2):

Just use this for **Dungeon Crawl** in Ubuntu 14.04 x64:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-dejavu-core
```

Comment: I was here trying to start dungeon crawl, but your solution did not worked for me...